# reloading store deletes filters

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a trigger-form-field which I use as a searchfield. Everytime the value changes, another search is performed. So far so good. But I have a PHP script which needs to be rerun every 30 seconds. For this I defined the following code in my

**grid.js**

```
setInterval(function() {
            var grid = Ext.getCmp('grid');
            var store = grid.getStore();
            store.load();
        }, 30000);
```

All this works just as expected, but every time my store is reloaded, my view and filters are gone. For example:

When I'm typing "test" in my searchfield, the grid is filtered correctly. But after refreshing the grid, the filter is not re-applied. I'd also like to keep the users view instead of being directed to the top of the page. Is that even possible?
Thanks for any help in advance.

I'm using ExtJS 4.2 if that matters

Answer (score 1):

why do you want to reload the store?? Just update the records and refresh the grid  view.